# Titanium Appcelerator - Disable copy and paste in textfield

Tags: javascript, textfield, copy-paste, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

How to disable pasting to a text in TextField?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, I suggest validating data which could minimize wrong information.

You can disable it from the front end as follows:

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="return false;" />
```